# JavaScript determine rows, columns and element relative position from a flat array given width and height

Tags: javascript

This is a simplified version of a more complex problem I have run into. I have simplified it to improve interpretation.

I have a single dimensional array which represents a grid of boxes with 3 elements per row and 4 elements per column. I cannot transform the array into a multi-dimensional array. The array looks like this:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'];
```

I know the height and width (as number of elements) of the array:

```
var width = 3;
var height = 4;
```

I am looking for some way to iterate the array and determine for any element which row it's in  and apply a function to all elements in that same row.

e.g.

```
// do something here to derive the 
// starting index and ending index of the row this element is in
// so I apply a function to only elements in that row

var startOfRow = getStartOfRow(myArray); // 2
var endOfRow = getEndtOfRow(myArray);    // 6

// in this case I need to know i=3 is the start of the row
// and i=5 is the end of the row 
// so i can do this:

for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
  if(i > startOfRow && i < endOfRow) {
    // affect all elements in the second row
    doStuff(myArray[i]);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the loop `Math.floor(i / 3)` will give you the row, `i % 3` will give you the column, both indices starting from 0.

So try...

```
for(i=0;i<myArray.length;i++) {
  var row = Math.floor(i / 3);
  var col = i % 3;
  // affect all elements in the second row
  if(row==1) {
    doStuff(myArray[i]);
  }
};
```